# "Google/Analytics.h file not found" after updating pod to GoogleAnalytics

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

I was using the pod s

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

but after running `pod install` I was receiving the following warning at the end of the pod installation

```
[!] Google has been deprecated
```

I searched in Google and I found that it is suggested to use the new pods

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

That removes the `pod install` warning. But makes my build fail with the following error in any file with the line:

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>                    (!error)Google/Analytics.h file not found
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `GoogleAnalytics` pod changed a few things as how the `Google/Analytics` pod worked. the Most important change is that GoogleAnalytics does not use the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` instead you should set up the tracker manually. Also the `Google/Analytics.h` file no longer exist, you must import the correct file, I leave you some examples.

```
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAILogger.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAITrackedViewController.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAITracker.h>
```

For more information check the dev guide
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

Answer (score 2):

Try delete this files (it will not break your project):

```
Pods 
*.xcworkspace
podfile.lock
```

and run `pod install`

If it does not help you please share your podfile.