# Error during archiving : 'GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h' file not found

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, google-analytics, azure-devops, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build a ionic app for iOS with azure devops build pipeline. I am using latest version of plugin `"cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.9.0"` I also tried to downgrade the plugin to `version 1.8.6` but not working.

```
cordova-plugin-google-analytics/UniversalAnalyticsPlugin.h:6:9: fatal error: 'GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h' file not found
```

[Open issue on github for this still no solution yet](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/579)

can anyone help with this? do I need to change a specific version?

Comment: Did you specify the `Cordova Version` of `Cordova Build` Task to `1.8.6` ? Besides, you could refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847411/google-analytics-h-file-not-found-after-updating-pod-to-googleanalytics) to add the related nodes in your ios project.

Comment: Running into the same issue, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Bill I added this `"cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "1.8.6"` in package json and it worked after few times don't know how but it does...and changing this version got me in me issue  sadly but you can give it a try

Comment: Yeah, I had that version initially, although it may have been ^1.8.6 which might have been using a newer version. Might try rolling back and see if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Ragesh Pikalmunde Glad to hear your problem is solved. You can convert your comment into an answer and mark it . So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line `"cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "1.8.6"` in package.json and run it. it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-google-analytics

npm uninstall @ionic-native/google-analytics

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics@1.8.6

npm install @ionic-native/google-analytics

ionic cordova platform rm ios 

ionic cordova platform add ios
```